# Scripting in QWS3270P Pulse mainframes.

Tags: shell, scripting, mainframe

I'm using qws3270P emulator to interact with mainframe. I just want to build/develop some script files. So that i can do 30m long repetitive process just by running the script file. The file format the emulator is accepting is .scr format. I have done a lot of research on it but i could not conclude with one. My interface has 3 screen to go to ISPF utilities. In first screen i need to type k, then enter, then next screen a, then next screen i need to enter User name and password, then enter then i will land to ISPF utilities

```
   key "enter"
   type "k"
   Key "enter"
   type "a"
   key "enter"
   type "username"
   key "Tab"
   key "password"
   key "enter"
   type "ispf"
```

In that emulator i could not able to go ispf. All the thing are projecting in Very first screen itself. Can anyone help me with this scripting code ?. i tried by using wait syntax also

Comment: Does the emulator have a record macro feature? might be easier to just do the task while recording the macro.

Comment: Then it will be a piece of cake, the current emulator i am using does not trace nor it does not record any macros.

Comment: Just a suggestion - terminal emulator scripts can be notorious to keep functioning...any small error during the process can throw things off - imagine what happens if you get a warning when logging on ("Your password will expire soon"...now there's an extra press of the enter key, etc). You'll be much happier if you figure out a mainframe shell script or batch job that does what you want, then submit it whenever you need to run it.